# Rat has been violently itching till it bleeds, what can I do?

Tags: behavior, health, rat

Okay so I have a pet Rat named Hope and she seems to be violently itching herself on her sides and face. Its forming a row of individual scabs ling one side that I can see when I bathe on her back and she will itch her face when I bathe her and I see blood on her hands and snout when she does. Is this normal or should I be concerned?

Comment: What do you mean "when I bathe her"? Rats a clean animals and clean themselves fine only if health allows them (their hands and legs are fine) and if they have a clean cage.

Comment: @Picard yes but you still need to bath them and her cage is clean

Comment: Have you been to the vet yet? Maybe it is some kind of an insect or some fungal infection. Usually I don't bath my rats and they have no such health problems.

Comment: @Picard yes he said that he didn't see anything wrong, also im glad you don't have to bath it's just my rat starts to get bald spots without bathing

Comment: Hopefully I didn't have this problem with any of my rats. I'd ask another vet for an opinion.

Comment: @Picard okay then

Comment: I don't know how your vet checked for the fungal infection but mine took a piece of fur and checked it under a microscope. Among humans skin problems could also a sign of allergy, so maybe your rat is allergic to something?

Comment: So? have you been to the vet? What did he say?

Comment: @Picard not yet